# Stepper Motor Z Axis Dropping

Tags: stepper-motor, failure

I have a current setup of a rack and pinion with a stepper motor moving a stage up and down the rack and pinion. I have encountered an issue with my stepper motor where when moving vertically in the Z-Axis, the motor will appear to have a minor skip and the entire stage will drastically fall down the entire rack. I understand it is probably a stalling/torque issue with the motor however I am confused as to why the stage falls all the way down.

Any thoughts?
Charlie

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the motor stall is not being monitored and handled properly.  In situations such as this, the normal response to a motor stall is to immediately stop phasing the motor and active the brake function of the motor driver.  Then, as long as the holding torque of the motor is greater than the load, the load will remain stationary.  When a stepper motor continues to get step pulses when it has stalled, various things may happen, none of them desirable.  One of which is for the motor to move in the opposite direction.

Comment: Hi Steve,

Thanks for the response! So you think it is a software thing to halt pulses from the Arduino when stalled? Should I connect the output of the motor to the Arduino that would indicate such a stall?

Thanks

Comment: Stepper motor are moved by a changing sequence of voltages to the motor's A+, A-, B+ and B- signals.  Often, a microcontroller is used to send the sequences to a motor driver chip which, (among other things) provides the (normally higher) voltage signals to the motor.  In many applications, an encoder is attached that provides feedback on the stepper motor's position.  A stall is detected when the encoder differs from the number of sequences sent by the microcontroller by more than a given amount.  I don't have enough experience with an Arduino to help you more in that respect.

Answer (score 0):

The stepper has a cogging effect but once you have force plus some momentum to get past one cog the rest will follow. It sounds like you need some combination of a counterbalance, a heftier stepper or to gear down the stepper output.

It should not skip steps if the motor is sized properly for the load (including reflected load inertia)